# Printing to console and processing an Array

Tags: f#, console.writeline

I'm processing a large number of object housed in an array.  This processing takes a long time, and I'd like to be able to monitor were the fx is in the processing step.

My goal is to be able to print to the console some sort of `Processing thing number *x*` while continuing to operate.  For example, with this

```
let x = [|1..10..100000|]

x 
|> Array.mapi (fun i n -> (i, n))
|> Array.map (fun (i, n) -> printfn "Processing n %i" i, (n * 2)))
|> Array.map snd
```

I get an output for every line.  What'd I'd *like* to have is every 10th or 100th or 1000 print a statement, rather than every line.  So I've tried

```
x 
|> Array.mapi (fun i n -> (i, n))
|> Array.map (fun (i, n) -> (if (i % 100 = 0) then printfn "Processing n %i" i, (n * 2)))
|> Array.map snd
```

but this provides an error over the `printfn...` bit with

```
The 'if' expression is missing an else branch. The 'then' branch has type
''a * 'b'. Because 'if' is an expression, and not a statement, add an 'else'
branch which returns a value of the same type.
```

I essentially want the `else...` branch to do nothing, print nothing to the console, just be ignored.

Interestingly, in writing this question and trying things in `FSI`, I tried this:

```
x 
|> Array.mapi (fun i n -> (i, n))
|> Array.map (fun (i, n) -> match (i % 100 = 0) with 
                            | true -> printfn "Processing n %i" i, (n * 2)
                            | false -> (), n * 2)
|> Array.map snd
```

which seems to work.  Is this the best way to provide the console text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
let x' = x |> Array.mapi (fun i n ->
        if i % 100 = 0 then
            printfn "Processing n %i" i
        n)
```

Both branches of an `if` expression must have the same type and

```
if (i % 100 = 0) then printfn "Processing n %i" i, (n * 2)
```

returns a value of type `(unit, int)` for the true case. The missing `else` case implicitly has type `()` so the types do not match. You can just print the value, ignore the result and then return the current value.

Comment: Perfect.  This is much less verbose than the `match` statement I had above!  Thanks.